# Cisco port ACL for one IP

Tags: cisco, security, acl, port-security

I'm running cisco WS-C4948-10GE (MPC8540) and having a vlan configured as following:

`ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.248`

My question is, How to create an ACL to limit the connections for ports 80 and 22 on IP **"192.168.1.2"** and allow access to it **only from 1.1.1.1 and 2.2.2.2?**

Please note that the other IPs on this subnet "192.168.1.3 - 192.168.1.6" should be normally accessed on all ports from everywhere.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hosts on the same vlan are not limited by the access list.

```
Access-list extended neteng-se
    Permit tcp host 1.1.1.1 host 192.168.1.2 eq www
    Permit tcp host 2.2.2.2 host 192.168.1.2 eq 22
    Deny ip any host 192.168.1.2
    Permit ip any any

Interface vlan 1
Ip access-list neteng-se out
```